# I2C Communication in AVR

Tags: avr, i2c

> The first step in a TWI transmission is to transmit a START condition. This is done by
> writing a specific value into TWCR, instructing the TWI hardware to transmit a START
> condition. Which value to write is described later on. However, it is important that the
> TWINT bit is set in the value written. Writing a one to TWINT clears the flag. The TWI will
> not start any operation as long as the TWINT bit in TWCR is set. Immediately after the
> application has cleared TWINT, the TWI will initiate transmission of the START condition.

This is a statement from the [datasheet of ATmega328P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf) (pg 223). What I don't understand is why is it necessary to set the TWINT bit, when I have an operation to perform (i.e. to transmit the START condition)? After all, it has mentioned:

> The TWI will not start any operation as long as the TWINT bit in TWCR is set.

And what does the `application has cleared TWINT` mean? If I am not wrong, application is the program to be uploaded into the micro-controller. If this is true, then the program should first set the TWINT bit and then reset it again. I am not getting the point it is trying to explain.

Comment: So are you trying to say that the TWI starts operation during the transition from HIGH to LOW?

Comment: i thought that i understood what it says, then i re-read it and it is totally confusing

Comment: i think that it says `write a 1 into the TWINT bit to cause the flag to  be cleared, which will  initiate transmission of the START condition` .... basically, writing a `1` sets the bit to `0`

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to send the start. When it is sent, the I2C peripheral sets TWINT bit and waits for the software for more commands what to do next. The software then updates whatever things are necessary to do next, and then clears the TWINT bit to zero so the peripheral then continues to do what it was told. So it must be kept set until everything is configured and set to zero to continue.

Basically, TWINT being set means previous operation is done and waiting for next operation.

And due to how the TWINT flag and many other flags work, it is not cleared by writing a zero bit, it is cleared by writing a one bit.

Comment: Your answer is contrasting the statement mentioned in the datasheet. It has mentioned that no any operations can start when the TWINT bit is set.

Comment: I am sorry for my horrible English. I misunderstood the use of "as long as".And thank you

Comment: @Giga-Byte, your English seems just fine

Comment: I am searching the use of "as long as" just because of this sentence.

Comment: as long as the sun shines, the earth won't freeze over ... it means `the same amount of time as` ... use of `while` would have  been better than `as long as` ... same as `while` in programming

Comment: It can be rephrased : the TWI will keep waiting until user clears the TWINT. The TWINT is set by the hardware when it completes an operation.